# Ensure every classes are autowired before postconstruct

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way to ensure the autowired components of the component that has components that are autowired to the another component to be initialized before postconstruct?
For example, If I have 3 components...

```
@Component
public class ComponentC {

    @Autowired
    private Component someOtherComponent

}

@Component
public class ComponentB {

    @Autowired
    private ComponentC componentC

}

@Component
public class ComponentA {

    @Autowired
    private ComponentB componentB

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // how can I ensure that componentC and someOtherComponent is initialized and ready?
    }

}
```

If I add @Autowired on the constructors of ComponentC and ComponentB and pass the beans as parameters, would that achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: You want that before creating Bean of `ComponentA`, `ComponentB` and `ComponentC` Bean must be created, I am right?

Comment: @Mehraj Malik in a nutshell, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Bring `@Autowired` to constructor level and force spring to add component after class hint.